# How to host a web app locally on my computer

Tags: docker, hosting

I have created a web app and I want to have it hosted locally on my computer so I can go to the browser and type `https://localhost:<port number>` and it will load up. However I am not sure how to do this or if it is even possible. My issue is I am not entirely sure what I need to google to get the answers and advice.

A little about what I have created and want to achieve:

- This web app is written in Angular with a Spring Boot back end that it calls with all the functionality (it is a little overkill but the aim was to learn Java and Spring Boot, I could have technically done it all in the front end)
- The data for this web app is stored in a MongoDB that is on my laptop
- I currently run `npm run dev` when I have been developing it which is `concurrently \"java -jar jars/java-fuel-consumption-api.jar\" \"npm start\" \"ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --open\"`
- I am not interested in having it hosted for others to use, it is just a simple personal project that I have written to help me learn JS and Spring Boot more
- I have a MacBook Air so I am not sure if there is anything already installed from Apple that can help
- I have got some experience of Docker and wouldn't say no to trying to learn a bit more
- I want it to be running in the background so I can just access it any time without doing an `npm run ...` command but have the ability to stop it when required (for updates and fixes)
- Not bothered about the URL - I assume that as it is being hosted on my computer it will just be `localhost`
- I want to avoid AWS/Azure with the reason is that I don't want to pay! It works by doing `npm run dev` but I just want to have it in a more professional manner

Sorry for the vauge question but I am in need of some advice of where to start - I know the end goal but like with most things like this I have little experience in how it needs to be acheived! Help to be pointed in the right direction is most appreciated.

Comment: If you want use it for yourself and practice and testing you can do it in your offline system too.you can use web servers .for example you can use xampp and run apache in it.(its commen for php).the usage of it its too  simple.download xampp.open its panel.run apache in it and local your project folder in "htdocs" directory.now its ready for use.

Comment: You should have a look at docker-compose ... thats exactly what you are looking for. It will start up all required services (backend, frontend, MongoDB, etc.) in docker containers with one single command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XAMPP, it's a, simple to install, Apache Server with DB: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

This will allow you to host anything locally.

Another option would be AWS, they offer some test/trial servers as well.